# VB.NET How to open a text file via OpenFileDialog into Array and the ListBox?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

My code is:

```
    Using dialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
            dialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.TXT;)|*.TXT|All files (*.*)|*.*"
            If (dialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK) Then
            proxies.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName))
            log.Text &= Environment.NewLine & "Proxies Loaded"
        End If
    End Using
```

It loads like this currently:

[image]

But I need to divide it into:

proxies[0] and a proxies[1]
0 being the IP and 1 being the port.

I need to use these in a Web Browser, later.

I can't seem to find a way to do this, whenever I try

```
proxies.split(":")
```

It give me an error:

```
.split isn't a member of system.windows.forms.listbox
```

Answer (score 1):

`proxies` is the ListBox. Either use `proxies.Items` or define an array instead.

I find it a little hard understanding your question but here's an example of putting the IPs and ports in the ListBox:

```
For Each address As String In File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName)
    proxies.Items.AddRange(address.Split(":"))
Next
```

Output:

Item 1: `1.160.129.53`

Item 2: `9064`

etc.

Comment: About to try this, looks exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just did something like this today you can use the replace function. The only difference is that I made it remove a prefix to the line. However you can do this to suffixes aswell. Give it a try.

```
Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Lines
Dim textreplace As String = "TYPE THE STUFF YOU WANT CUT OFF IN HERE"
Dim texttoreplace As String = ""
Dim textline As String = lines(30)'The Line # you have it on. Remember the line 1 is line 0
textline = textline.Replace(textreplace, texttoreplace)
TextBox2.Text = textline 'Here the text is sent in
```

FOR YOUR CASE: (Just doing the first one in your list "1.106.129.53:9064")(You may have to have separate textboxes to perform this.)This separates the ip and port but leaves the port.

```
Dim lines() As String = seperate_textbox_or_you_can_use_another_way_to_load_it.Lines
Dim textreplace As String = "1.106.129.53:"
Dim texttoreplace As String = ""
Dim textline As String = lines(1)'The Line # you have it on. Remember the line 1 is line 0
textline = textline.Replace(textreplace, texttoreplace)
log.Text = textline 'Here the text is sent in
```

Comment: That seems rather complicated in my opinion.

Comment: That does seem rather complicated, you could acomplish the same with less lines, I just can't remember the line..

Comment: Yeah its from one of my programs that I made. I purposely made it complicated so reverse engineering it would be a pain. Lol sorry for it being complicated.

Comment: It does, just tested it. I actually have a use for it, in another project!

Answer (score 0):

```
            For Each address As String In File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName)
                proxies.Items.AddRange(address.Split(":"))
                Dim ip As String = proxies.Items(0)
                Dim port As String = proxies.Items(1)
            Next
```

Is what I was looking for.

Comment: That was what I wrote, wasn't it :)? The only difference is that you assigned two strings with item 1 and 2. (:

Comment: But I'm curious about why you declare the strings inside the loop?

Comment: Yea it is, but the .Items was also add, and thanks for that!  More than 1 proxy, about 20,000.

Comment: Oh, I missed typing `.Items` (: